# printing names after the while loop

Tags: java

I'm practicing on my java and I'm having issues trying to figure out how to print the names entered from the user. I placed name in the print statement and it didn't work. I also tried concatenating it also no luck. If someone could show me in the right direction that would be great

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class name{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a name or type END to exit");

    String name = "name";
    int i = 0;  

    while(i < 10){
    System.out.print("Type your name: ");
    i++;

    name = input.next(); 
    if(name.equals("end"))break;    
    }
      System.out.print(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Follow proper formatting when posting code here, for easier reading.

Comment: Walk through it, line-by-line, following your own instructions. What gets printed, if you have one print statement after the loop, after name equals "end"?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that implementation will only print out the last name.
A collection e.g. nameList can be used to add each name as they are being put in the list

```
import java.util.*;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a name or type END to exit");

        String name;

        ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10) {
            System.out.print("Type your name: ");
            i++;

            name = input.next();
            nameList.add(name);
            if (name.equals("end")) break;
        }
        System.out.println(nameList);
    }

}
```

If you dont want 'end' to appear in the final output you can swap the `break` line and the `.add` line